# UISearchController - not playing well with child view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have an issue where my current configuration is:

UITableViewController -> UINavigationController -> A ViewController for swapping out 2 child view controllers.

Each child view controller has a UISearchController associated with them. When the UISearchBar activates, it never seems to have the correct position.

```
extension MySearchViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {

    func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        var adjustedOrigin = searchController.searchBar.frame.origin
        //FIXME: There's some odd behavior with embedded child VCs where the status bar adjustments are not taken into consideration
        adjustedOrigin.y += UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
        searchController.searchBar.frame.origin = adjustedOrigin
        definesPresentationContext = false
        navigationController?.definesPresentationContext = true
        navigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    }

    func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }

    func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        var adjustedOrigin = searchController.searchBar.frame.origin
        //FIXME: There's some odd behavior with embedded child VCs where the status bar adjustments are not taken into consideration
        adjustedOrigin.y -= UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height

        searchController.searchBar.frame.origin = adjustedOrigin
    }

}
```

You can see in the above that the origin is adjusted as I'm trying to manually correct the offsets of the UISearchBar, which is by far not preferred. I've attempted checking off (in numerous areas) the display under  from the storyboard and via code almost everywhere within the hierarchy. I can't seem to find the offsetting culprit. By default, the UISearchBar will appear all the way under the status bar as such:

[image: search screen]

This is without my manual adjustments which are still a bit off.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

---

Edit 1:

Further proof that something in a parent VC is messing up the offset, the actually superView of the UISearchBar is offsetted by -20 when presenting. Hence the following corrects the issue:

```
import UIKit

class MySearchController: UISearchController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        edgesForExtendedLayout = .Top
        extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true 

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print(active)

        if active && searchBar.superview!.frame.origin != CGPoint.zero {
            searchBar.superview?.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you have any weird constraints any of the VC's child or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The UISearchController is separate from auto layout constraints on the child VCs. The only thing that would be affected is the UISearchBar (which is in a container when injected into the UISearchController during presentation mode). The UISearchBar has translates mask constraints set appropriately to not utilize a specified constraint based layout.

Comment: For the most part, this is definitely something communicating something up the chain for whatever is communicating the contextual offsets, that much I know.

Comment: @TheCodingArt did you ever manage to find a fix for that?

Comment: @jbouaziz there wasn't a concrete answer beyond a small hack I used to manually correct the behavior I saw. I'll attach an answer below that maybe able to at least assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was the only way I found that could reliably adjusted for the status bar offset the search controller was incorrectly adjusting for.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    //FIXME: Unfortunate hack required to adjust for offset of -20 pulled from ????? where ?????
    guard let searchBarContainerView = searchBar.superview where (active && searchBarContainerView.frame.origin != CGPoint.zero) else {
        return
    }
    searchBarContainerView.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
}
```

Note that the physical origin was offset by `-20` being the height of the status bar. The correction was to ensure the origin was set to 0 forcefully.

Also note that this is an overridden method within the `UISearchController` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: usually the key in this kind of weirdness is who is defining the presentation context.

From the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext

*When a context-based presentation occurs, UIKit starts at the presenting view controller and **walks up the view controller hierarchy. If it finds a view controller whose value for this property is true, it asks that view controller to present the new view controller**. If no view controller defines the presentation context, UIKit asks the window’s root view controller to handle the presentation.*

So basically you have to make sure that the right view controller in your hierarchy is setting that to definesPresentationContext to YES. No offsets or frame modifications are needed if this is correctly placed. In your case is probably your parent VC the one that needs to define the presentation context and make sure that no child VC sets that to YES.

Comment: If you reference the code above, that exact value has been manipulated too down with no success. I have that particular flag set appropriately and did (back when this was made) manipulate it to match what I expected without success. So unless you have a working code sample for this situation, this answer means nothing and contributes nothing to the question beyond posting documentation.

Comment: my feeling is that you are misunderstanding the usage of the definesPresentationContext as you are disabling it on willPresent and enabling back on didPresent, IMHO this flag tells which view controller in the hierarchy of parent/childVC is going to be responsable for presenting the searchVC so it's constraints are applied to keep the view in the proper place, so set it to true on the presenter of the search bar. In my own experience when you have to tweak offsets, frames etc... to keep things into place it's usually a bad smell that means something is conceptually wrong. hope this helps.

Comment: I don't misunderstand the usage, but ok. There was a reason todo this back here when testing this scenario. Regardless, this doesn't provide a solution rather just an opinionated commentary.